# i want to use dodirectpayment with cron job for recurring payments. our tester said cron job are vulnerable and can be hacked

Tags: php, paypal, cron

I want to use dodirectpayment with cron job for recurring payments. our tester said cron job are vulnerable and can be hacked. is this the right approach or not? I need to do following task plan can be upgraded/downgrade any time with the recurring profile.

Comment: IMHO, based on your comments below, your first order of concern in the context of _"vulnerable and hackable"_ should be **storage of card data in your systems** ...

Answer (score 1):

I've seen malware creating cron jobs to re-infect files if they're cleaned, but as long as you follow standard security practices on your server your cron jobs in general should not be vulnerable to any attacks.  I use cron jobs for variable recurring payment solutions quite a bit and have never had any issues.

On that note, you don't want to be running DoDirectPayment every time the cron runs.  For that to work you would have to be storing CC data in your database so that you could populate the request every time it runs.  This is not a good practice.

Instead, You call DoDirectPayment the first time a customer submits a transaction with you, and then in the future you can call DoReferenceTransaction to process variable amounts at any time you need using the same card data that PayPal stored on their servers for the original transaction.

When you call DoReferenceTransaction you just pass in that original transaction ID and the new amount you need to charge.  This way you don't have to store that data on your server, but instead can let PayPal handle that.

Comment: Thanks mr.Andrew for your reply. i can not use DoReferenceTransaction because i have to hit with back up card if primary card fails that's why i am using cron job. But never the less thanks for that detailed explaination.

Comment: You can, and should, still use DoReferenceTransaction.  All cards (both primary and backup) should be tokenized for safety and NOT stored directly in your system. Otherwise you are taking a big risk of credit card theft for which you might be liable. Also: even if you tokenize rather than store the card numbers, if you handle the raw credit card numbers AT ALL you still need to meet the relevant PCI regulations or you could be liable for compromised cards. I would strongly advise you to get some advice from a payments expert.

Comment: Thanks mr geewiz for that great reasoning.so i should not store credit card information on the system. so i should make recurring profiles for users and then charge them what do you say?